# Angular directive to append asterisk in label text

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, angular-directive

As found out in SO, we can create a custom directive to append required validation asterisk for an element as specified below:

```
mod.directive("mandatory", function() {
       return {
           restrict: 'A',
           compile: function(element) {
              element.after("*");
           }
       };
    });
```

I've one simple label tag as follows:

```
<label mandatory>Name</label>
```

What it does is it creates the following html content as follows:

```
 <label mandatory>Name</label>*
```

What I want is the following html content:

```
<label mandatory>Name*</label>
```

I've tried the .text, .html, .appends functions of the element, but it didn't reflect any changes.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to set the text in this way:

```
mod.directive("mandatory", function() {
       return {
           restrict: 'A',
           compile: function(element) {
              element.text(element.text() + "*");
           }
       };
    });
```

However, instead of manipulating the element directly, I would opt for a template or something like that.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. Yes indeed using a template is ideal.